# order number different from index number

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have this situation, where i have to pick a word so the program will print out the meaning of the word, but the order number doesnt match the index numberx, example (1,2,3) but indexes are (0,3,7), and next time it may be (1,2,3) and index (1,3,5), can you please help how i can solve the issue of this. i want any solution, if select the second word i want the meaning of it. thank you with respect umer selmani

```
empt_list=[]
    empt_list_meaning=[]
    def game():
            empt_dict = dict(zip(empt_list, empt_list_meaning))
            a_options = input("Please select one of these options: ")
            if a_options == 1:
                a_newword = str(raw_input("What word you want to add? "))
                empt_list.append(a_newword)
                a_newword_meaning=str(raw_input("add the meaning of the word: "))
                empt_list_meaning.append(a_newword_meaning)

            elif a_options == 2:
                a_select_word = raw_input("select the words, you want")
                zero = 0
                for word in empt_dict:
                    if a_select_word in word:
                        zero += 1
                        print zero, word,
                        print empt_dict.keys().index(word)

            print ("would you like to continue or exit?\n1.contine\n2.exit")
            now = input(">>> ")
            if now == 1:
                game()
            else:
                print "bye"

game()
```

here you go, output.

```
"C:\Users\Umer Selmani\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Umer Selmani/.PyCharm2017.3/config/scratches/scratch_10.py"
Please select one of these options: 1
What word you want to add? ball
add the meaning of the word: round shape item
would you like to continue or exit?
1.contine
2.exit
>>> 1
Please select one of these options: 1
What word you want to add? cactus
add the meaning of the word: flower type
would you like to continue or exit?
1.contine
2.exit
>>> 1
Please select one of these options: 1
What word you want to add? fall
add the meaning of the word: season
would you like to continue or exit?
1.contine
2.exit
>>> 1
Please select one of these options: 2
select the words, you wantll
1 ball 0
2 fall 2
would you like to continue or exit?
1.contine
2.exit
>>> 2
bye
```

Comment: The standard Python dictionary is not ordered.

Comment: @Mr.T, yeah but then always will have the same order of unorderedness

Comment: Better is to use **OrderedDict()** of **collections** module. In this way you will be able to preserve the order of elements unlike the in-built dictionary.

Comment: @umerselmani That is not true. Run `print(dict(zip(list("ABCD"), range(4))))` several times to see that the order is not preserved. [Ordered dictionaries are indeed an option in 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 0):

Like others have commented, dictionaries are not ordered by default in Python 2. The only real problem with your code then is the first line in the game function. Try something like this:

```
empt_list=[]
empt_list_meaning=[]
def game():
        # Dict not needed
        #empt_dict = dict(zip(empt_list, empt_list_meaning))
        # add clarification of what the options are
        print 'Press 1 to add a word or 2 to search for a word.'
        a_options = input("Please select one of these options: ")
        if a_options == 1:
            a_newword = str(raw_input("What word you want to add? "))
            empt_list.append(a_newword)
            a_newword_meaning=str(raw_input("add the meaning of the word: "))
            empt_list_meaning.append(a_newword_meaning)

        elif a_options == 2:
            a_select_word = raw_input("select the words, you want")
            # Use enumerate instead of variable here
            #zero = 0
            for zero, word in enumerate(empt_list):
                if a_select_word in word:
                    #zero += 1
                    # Index the lists you already have instead of indexing the keys of an unordered dict
                    print zero, word, empt_list_meaning.index(word)
                    print empt_list_meaning[zero]

        print ("would you like to continue or exit?\n1.contine\n2.exit")
        now = input(">>> ")
        if now == 1:
            game()
        else:
            print "bye"
game()
```